# What is the safest way to run an executable on Linux?

Tags: linux, language-agnostic, gcc, sandbox

I am trying to run a program compiled from C code from an unknown source. I want to make sure that the program  does not harm my system in anyway. Like for instance, the program might have soemthing like `system("rm -rf /")` in the source, which is un-detectable, unless the code is thoroughly examined.

I thought of the following 2 ways

1. Run it inside a VM like VMWare
2. Build a windows exe on linux and run on wine

Both are not very elegant solutions and I cannot automate them. and also, in case of 1, it can harm the VM.

Any help would be appreciated.

I want to run the program in what we can call a "sandbox".

Comment: I've thought about chroot, but it does not stop fork bombs and other system call problems. Thanks

Comment: Similar Qs on sandboxing/jailing processes in Linux or Unix:

* http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/6433/4319
* http://stackoverflow.com/q/4410447/94687
* http://stackoverflow.com/q/4249063/94687
* http://stackoverflow.com/q/1019707/94687

Comment: wine has absolutely no value in containing the executable. Run a wine executable as root and you can wipe your system

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Geordi](http://www.eelis.net/geordi/) uses a combination of chroot and interception of syscalls to compile and then sandbox arbitrary code.

Comment: Geordi source has a lot of ideas I can use. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Check out [seccomp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seccomp).  It was designed for this use case.

Answer (score 5):

I wrote an [overview of sandboxing methods on Linux *(archived)*](http://web.archive.org/web/20121129121538/http://blog.technologyofcontent.com/2011/04/sandboxing-for-multi-tenant-applications) here. You are best off using Linux containers (lxc) or selinux, in my view. You could use a virtualisation solution and automate it, but it is a lot more effort.

lxc will isolate your processes, filesystem and network, and you can set resource limits on the container. There are still risks of a kernel attack, but they are much reduced.

Answer (score 2):

You can use something like [schroot](http://www.debian-administration.org/articles/566) and chroot the program, but anything of sufficient nastiness will bust out of that.

You best bet is probably a virtual machine (vmware or virtualbox) and taking a snapshot before compiling and running the program. That way you can roll back if something goes horribly wrong.

Comment: In fact, you should just roll it back after testing anyway, because you might not have noticed what went horribly wrong.

Comment: @caf True, if it's untrusted then it's untrusted. Don't muck about and rollback anyway.

Comment: Virtual machines are not exactly a secure environment either, if the program being executed knows it's in one.

Answer (score 1):

Create an user that has write access only to non-critical directories. Run the program as that user. If you are also interested in privacy, consider also restricting its read rights.

Answer (score 1):

The wikipedia page for [chroot](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chroot) may be a good start. It describes chroot and also provides links to a few, more thorough alternatives.

Answer (score 1):

`chroot` is one possibility if you want to isolate it from everything else but still have an environment for it to run in.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/chroot

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BasicChroot

Answer (score 0):

Run it on a non-networked computer that you will re-image once it's done. There is no safe way to run it on a machine and continue to trust that machine afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

In addition of other answers, using `strace` or `ltrace` may help you to understand what the program is doing.