# How to disable socket creation for a Linux process, for sandboxing?

Tags: linux, sockets, sandbox

I'm considering several options for sandboxing a Linux process. Using `clone()` with `CLONE_NEWNET` (etc.) is one of the options. `CLONE_NEWNET` ensures that the sandboxed process cannot make or accept real network connections. But I'd like to disable sockets entirely for that process, even `bind()`ing to any port on `0.0.0.0`, and binding to a Unix doman socket (even anonymous). I'd like to do this to prevent the process from using too much kernel resources by binding to thousands of ports. How do I do that?

In general, I'm interested in many sandboxing approaches (i.e. those provided by the Linux kernel and those enforced by `ptrace()`), but in this question I'm only interested in the socket creation aspect of the sandboxing approaches (so if you suggest a sandboxing approach, please also explain how to prevent socket creation with it), and I'm not interested in approaches which need kernel patching or which involve loading a kernel module which is not part of the Ubuntu Lucid default binary kernel package, or which would affect every process on the system.

Comment: Similar Qs on sandboxing/jailing processes in Linux or Unix:

* http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/6433/4319

* http://stackoverflow.com/q/3859710/94687

* http://stackoverflow.com/q/4249063/94687

* http://stackoverflow.com/q/1019707/94687

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`ptrace` seems to be the most obvious tool but aside from that…

util-linux[-ng] has a command [`unshare`](http://karelzak.blogspot.com/2009/12/unshare1.html), which uses the kernel's [`clone`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/clone.2.html)/[`unshare`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/unshare.2.html) interfaces.  If you run the new process through`unshare -n` (or `clone(CLONE_NEWNET)`), any network sockets it creates are in a different namespace.  That doesn't solve the kernel resource issue but it does sandbox the process.

The Linux kernel also supports [seccomp](http://git.kernel.org/?p=linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux-2.6.git;a=blob;f=kernel/seccomp.c;hb=HEAD), a mode entered with `prctl(PR_SET_SECCOMP, 1)` which prevents the process (well, thread, really) from calling any syscalls other than `read`, `write`, `exit`, and `sigreturn`.  It's a pretty effective sandbox but difficult to use with unmodified code.

You can define a SELinux domain which disallows `socket`/`bind`/etc. calls, and perform a dynamic transition into that type.  This (obviously) requires a system with an actively enforcing SELinux policy.  (Possibly similar things are possible with AppArmor and TOMOYO, but I'm not very familiar with any of them.)

Comment: Thank you for composing such a comprehensive list. I've accepted your answer. I've tried AppArmor, and I can confirm that it can prevent socket creation. I have already mentioned `CLONE_NEWNET` in the question (and why it isn't a solution). seccomp is not a good answer to my question, because it restricts more (e.g. fork()) than what I want.

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at [systrace](http://www.citi.umich.edu/u/provos/systrace/) - not limited to sockets, but a generic syscall policy generator/enforcer. Quote:

> GNU/Linux port is finished and kernel patch is maintained actively by Marius Eriksen. **Can be run without kernel changes using the ptrace backend.**

Disclamer - I never tried it on Linux.

Comment: Thank you for mentioning systrace. I've just taken a look at it on Linux i386, and it looks powerful in terms of features: it can prevent socket creation, and much more. I had about five small problems compiling it, but once that was done, it seemed to work for sandboxing simple programs, but I couldn't sandbox GCC calling GNU as(1) with systrace: systrace got stuck indefinitely in a wait4 system call. Also, it's unmaintained for 2 years. So I've given up on it. since an earlier wait4 bugreport was unanswered: http://forum.soft32.com/linux/strace-wait4-pending-SIGALRM-ftopict484715.html

Comment: FYI I've voted up your answer, but since systrace isn't stable for me, I can't accept this answer.

Answer (score 2):

Try seccomp (see the prctl man page), it can confine your process to only accessing the sockets that were left open at the time the prctl call was made.

Comment: I know about seccomp, but that's not a good answer to my question, because it restricts more (e.g. fork()) than what I want.

Comment: pts: I agree.  Tangentially, this is why seccomp2 should have been accepted into mainline Linux instead of getting sneered at.

Comment: Where is this seccomp2 you speak of? Link to mailing list archive having the post?

Comment: "Adam Langley (also of Google) has posted a patch which does just that. The new 'mode 2' implementation accepts a bitmask describing which system calls are accessible."  Found on [LWN](http://lwn.net/Articles/332974/) with lots of links.

Answer (score 2):

You might be interested with "**sydbox**" sandbox or "**pinktrace**" library :

http://www.diigo.com/user/wierzowiecki/sydbox

Comment: Thanks for mentioning these two. I discarded them early because they are horribly underdocumented. Maybe they will improve in the future.

Comment: I had same feeling at beginning. Lucky, I decided to check out sources, and posts on mailing lists and I've found that this project looks interesting and finally, it's not as small that it feels on begging, and offers many ways of comfortable "filtering" of system calls - in flexible manner ! :)

Comment: In my workload (running g++), sydbox was 50% slower than User-mode Linux, so I'm sticking to User-mode Linux now, because that gives me not only sandboxing, but limiting gross memory use.

Answer (score 2):

If your main goal is to limit the number of sockets that are opened by some benign process P applied to benign inputs, then `setrlimit(RLIMIT_NOFILE, ...)` will do approximately what you want.

However, if P is assumed be to malicious rather than benign or if you're looking for strong assurance about how P will behave in the face of potentially malicious inputs, then you're probably out of luck: i.e., at best, with the tools available today, you can create an obstacle course for attackers.

(That being said, if an obstacle course works for you, then you might get some more good ideas by poking around over here at [sandboxing.org](http://sandboxing.org) or by sending your questions to the friendly folks on `sandboxing-talk@lists.sandboxing.org`.)